# I am having trouble import the React-hexgrid library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, import

I have checked the path in the library is correct but it still gives me error
i use

```
"react-hexgrid": "2.0.1",
"react": "18.2.0"
"next": "13.4.3"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KHUS.png)

I'm waiting for help from the author  [Link](https://github.com/Hellenic/react-hexgrid/issues/115)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `node_modules` folder and install the dependencies by typing

`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Reload the server and it should work just fine.

Comment: it doesn't work. my project uses nextjs. i think it does not work with nextjs